# How to profile python script run as "named module"?

Tags: python, profiler, cprofile

How to profile a python module runs by command `python -m foo.bar`?

Seems that `python -m foo.bar -m cProfile -o test.out` is totally weird, and doesn't work here.

Comment: The linked duplicate provides a workaround.  There is an [open Python issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue9325) about this but it seems to have stalled.